# Stop PDFs made by PDFCreator with Epson printers being enlarged

Tags: pdf, pdfcreator

I'm using PDFCreator to create PDF files but when I print these files on my Epson printer, it automatically enlarges the original file so that it cannot fit one single page.

I tried on different printers and find that this kind of problem only exists on the Epson printers.

How do I get it to print properly?

Comment: How many different Epson printers did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Select the "Fit to page" option before printing.

The page(s) will be rescaled to only be as large as the destination page size allows.